# Smart GWT app displays nothing because nocache.js file not found error

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, smartgwt

I have a smart GWT app example  called `AwesomesmartGWTUIProject` from 
 javacodegeeks

Its package is `com.javacodegeeks.smartgwt.appui`

In eclipse when i try to run it as a web application I get the following error

```
In order for your application to run correctly, you will need to include these tags in   your host page directly. In order to avoid this error, you will need to remove the script tags from the gwt.xml file, or add this property to the gwt.xml file: <set-configuration-property name='xsiframe.failIfScriptTag' value='FALSE'/>
[ERROR] shell failed in doSlowStartup method
Mar 31, 2014 10:07:41 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet  doGet
WARNING: No file found for: /awesomesmartgwtuiproject/com.javacodegeek.smartgwt.appui.awesomesmartgwtuiproject.nocache.js
```

It simply doesn't display anything when I try to run it in my browser. Am new to smartGwt so am not so conversant with the configurations. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

> Have you compiled your GWT project?
>
> Is there nocache.js file generated in your project at correct location?

You have to read about [Understanding the GWT Compiler](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html).

Every thing is defined at above link including project structure, GWT compilation etc.

Use `rename-to` attribute in your module gwt.xml file.

Directly from the above link:

> You may have noticed that one of the generated files is named after your module, followed by a .nocache.js suffix. This is the GWT bootstrap file. Similar to the output subdirectory war/, the name of this file is also controlled by the rename-to attribute in your module XML file.